# Django - How to add admin.py in my app folder?

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to add `admin.py` in my app folder.

Currently the app folder contains the following files:

```
__init__.py
models.py
test.py
views.py
```

Any help will do :-)

Comment: What is the problem? Are you able to create a file?

Comment: @Tadeck:  I need to edit admin.py so that my app can show up on the admin page. I am following a tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin)

Comment: Just manually create a file named `admin.py` in the app folder and continue following the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial say to edit `admin.py` in the `polls` directory.  However, if you're just starting a new project `admin.py` will not exist.

You can simply create a blank `admin.py` file and add the contents suggested by the tutorial.  Django will automatically notice any admin settings from this file when the admin app is enabled.